# Interaction.id replying with undefined

Tags: discord.js

Whenever i try to reply with the ID's of a channel in variable's roblox, and discord it return's undefined here's my code.

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../../schemas/configuration');

module.exports = async (interaction, guild) => {
    var roblox;
    var discord;

    if (interaction.customId === 'discord_logs') {
        discord = interaction.values[0];

        await interaction.reply({ content: `The channel will receive logs when you save the changes.`, ephemeral: true });

        console.log(discord);
    }

    if (interaction.customId === 'roblox_logs') {
        roblox = interaction.values[0];

        await interaction.reply({ content: `The channel will receive logs when you save the changes.`, ephemeral: true });
        console.log(roblox);
    }

    if (interaction.customId === 'setup_save') {
        await interaction.reply({ content: `Updated logging channels for ${roblox}, and ${discord}`, ephemeral: true });
    }
};
```

[image: After pressing save.]

I tried to push the ID's to an array but when i did it replaced each other for example i pushed roblox and when i pushed discord it replaced roblox. I was expecting for bot array's to be pushed or the variable's roblox and discord to have the ID'S.

Comment: Your variables are declared within the function scope (i.e every time the function is called) and are never assigned a value for the `setup_save` condition

Comment: Thanks for the help never noticed that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)